# FormData always empty

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener, form-data

I have an html page with a form and a js script with a listener on a button.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="login.js" defer></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form id="form">
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td>Username</td>
          <td><input type="text" id="user" value=""></td>
        </tr>  
        <tr>
          <td>password</td>
          <td><input type="text" id="pass" value=""></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
      <button type="button" id="btn">send</button>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

```
const form = document.getElementById("form");
const btn = document.getElementById("btn");

btn.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
  const payload = new FormData(form);

  console.log([...payload]);
})
```

the result from console log is:
[]
[[prototype]]:array(0)

Somebody knows why formdata is empty?

I have tried also like this

```
const form  = e.target.closest('form');
```

same result.
If I log document.getElementById("user").value it prints the value, so something in the formdata should be.

Comment: Your inputs don't name any `name` attributes. `FormData(form)` uses the names, not the IDs.

Comment: So change `id="user/pass"` to `name="user/pass"` and you'll get what you expect.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you want to make your submit button have a type of 'submit' and then having your event listener listen to the 'submit' event on your form.

```js
const form = document.getElementById('form')
console.log(form);
form.addEventListener("submit", (event) => {
  const data = new FormData(event.target);
  const name = data.get("name");
  console.log(name);
});
```

```html
<form id="form">
  <input type="text" name="name" value=""/>
  <button type="submit" id="btn">Save</button>
</form>
```

[Here](https://matiashernandez.dev/blog/post/handling-forms-with-vanilla-javascript) is a post that you can read about forms.

Comment: OP's event listener on the button is fine. You actually put in the solution, you just didn't mention it. The problem is their input fields don't have a name.

Answer (score 0):

FormData will only use input fields that use the name attribute.
Please update html as following.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="login.js" defer></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form id="form">
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td>Username</td>
          <td><input type="text" id="user" name="user" value=""></td>
        </tr>  
        <tr>
          <td>password</td>
          <td><input type="text" id="pass" name="pass" value=""></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
      <button type="button" id="btn">send</button>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Javascript code is fine.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should listen for the submit event on the form. I call `e.preventDefault()` in the submit event listener to stop the submit action.

Second, replace all the id attributes with name attributes. The input elements are only part of the data of the form when they have a name. And on top of that names do not have to be unique throughout the HTML document like the ids have to be. And now you have no global variables floating around (easier to maintain).

```js
document.forms.form01.addEventListener('submit', e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  let payload = new FormData(e.target);
  console.log([...payload]);
});
```

```html
<form name="form01">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>Username</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="user" value=""></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>password</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="pass" value=""></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <button type="submit">send</button>
</form>
```